# HQL Table with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value for column

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

I'm trying to create a table in Hadoop but with the current_timestamp() as default value for a column:

```
CREATE TABLE table_test(
      CODE_FIRST         VARCHAR(3),
      TYPE_TEST_1        VARCHAR(4),
      TYPE_TEST_2        VARCHAR(4),
      FLAG_BOOL          VARCHAR(1),
      CONTACT            VARCHAR(15),
      DATE_MODIFIED      TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
) STORED AS parquet TBLPROPERTIES("parquet.compress"="GZIP");
```

I've tried to change it to `AS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and many other formats but I'm not able to create the table. Could someone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Hive version 2.1.1-mapr-1901

The error:

```
Error while compiling statement: 
FAILED: ParseException line 50:25 mismatched input 'DEFAULT' expecting ) near 'TIMESTAMP' in create table statement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEFAULT` constraint in Hive DDL was implemented in version **3.0**, see JIRA [HIVE-18726](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-18726).

> Ashutosh Chauhan added a comment - 22/May/18 23:16
>
> This jira is
> resolved and released with Hive 3.0 If you find an issue with it,
> please create a new jira.

But even in that version, you can only define the constraints on *MANAGED* tables, and *MANAGED* tables do not support Parquet format.

For *EXTERNAL* tables (that can work with Parquet files), only `RELY` constraint is supported, according to [Hive manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Managed+vs.+External+Tables).